# loopback: geo query with mongo 2.2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback for querying a MongoDb database. The database has a old version I must deal with, `2.2`.

Unfortunately, it seems it cannot perform query with `near` clause, as it composes an object like:

```
location: {
    $near: {
      $geometry: {
        coordinates: [12.0684,41.2432],
        type: 'Point',
      },
    },
    $maxDistance: 10
}
```

instead, the db version I'm using allows a query in this format:

```
location: {
    $near: [12.0684,41.2432],
    $maxDistance: 10
}
```

My question is: **is there a way I can force the `loopback-connector-mongodb` to fallback in a query like the latter?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way of doing this. You need to get the connector, extract the collection and do the query. Something like this:

```
 Model.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
   var collection = db.collection(Model.getModelName());
   collection.find(query, function (err, res) { // define whichever query you need
     if(err) {
       cb(err);
       return;
     }
     res.toArray(function (err, realRes) { // this part is crucial
     // otherwise if you try to print res you will get a dump of the db object
       if(err) {
         cb(err);
         return;
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The point is this way I can no longer use loopback query abstraction. I see in my example it isn't clear, but this query filter is part of a larger query - most of which is shared by other methods.